# Does Mongo SpringData findAll support batch fetching

Tags: optimization, batch-processing, spring-data-mongodb

I have SOLR feeding mechanizm, it fetches all orders from mongo base and process them (fetch additional data and creates SOLR document).
My problem is that number of records is above 100k, so fetching them all into a list and processing is just wrong.

Can SpringData support batching list query? So that I could work on smaller chunks of data and process them?

I could work like this:

```
interface Command {
/*
 Here I will define logic that transforms mongo entry list
 into SOLR documents and sends an update
*/
  void execute(List<D> input); // here I will put my logic
}
```

And in my service I would like to execute findAll like this:

```
Command commandExecutor = ...;//implement Executor
int batchSize = 500;
mongoTemplate.findAll(MyModel.class, commandExecutor , batchSize );
```